# Excluding value in AWS CLI command output value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am working on a task to get all instances from all the region in an aws account along with other details, my requirement is to exclude the windows instances. I have tried a lot with changes but not getting desired results, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key=='"'Name'"']|[0].Value,InstanceId,State.Name,PublicIpAddress,PrivateIpAddress,Placement.AvailabilityZone,PlatformDetails]' --filters Name=platform,Values!=windows --output table
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be to try with `aws ssm describe-instance-information` instead of `aws ec2 describe-instances`if you have `ssm` available on all the nodes.
You can get all the result with

```
aws ssm describe-instance-information --region us-east-1 --max-items 2
```

Also you can try

```
aws ssm describe-instance-information --query 'InstanceInformationList[*][PlatformType==`Linux`,InstanceId]'  --region us-east-1 --max-items 2
```

which can give you instance id and true or false if there is Linux/windows.

Additional requirements from the comment (IP, AZ etc) :
You can try with
`aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*][][KernelId,Placement.[AvailabilityZone][],PublicIpAddress]' --region us-east-1 --max-items 2`
You can add other filters as well.
As for the question about windows and linux, you can filter by `KernelID`. I don't have a windows server so I can't check but my guess is this field won't be present.

Comment: IIn my requirement I need to get the publicIP, Status of instance and region/AZ as well from the output. which I doubt will get with this query

Comment: @Devops-Learner, added another query for AZ and public ip as region is the one where you query. You can add state/status to the query as well.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be forgetting this "$*!@%" 'CLI' (which in fact is a Python interpreter, with all in text mode)... with its monkey syntax and case sensitivity... and install pwsh and enjoy a pure object-oriented and orthogonal environment.

Once there,

Get-EC2Instance | Select-Object -Expand Instances | Where-Object Platform -eq "Windows"

or

Get-EC2Instance | Select -Expand Instances | ? Platform -ne "Windows"

And many, many, many other advantages...